# I want to include a certain div from another url into my site

Tags: javascript, html

I have this

```
<div> 
  <object type="text/html" data="https://www.urlIWantTheDivFrom.com"
   width="800px" height="600px">
  </object>
/div>
```

However this gives me the whole webpage. I want to copy a certain div. I also tried some `js`. However I cannot find out how to copy the exact div as well

```
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="https://www.urlIWantTheDivFrom.com" ></object>';
```

Comment: Not going to happen like that. You can not control another domain.

Comment: Not possible. However If the other site allows CORS you may be able to do `$("#myDiv").load("https://www.urlIWantTheDivFrom.com #idOfDiv")`. Alternative is to have a proxy on your own server

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy will generally prevent this. You'll need to do this server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding another webpage content is not allowed by default, but here is a thing which you may try using jQuery ajax:

```
$.get('https://www.urlIWantTheDivFrom.com', function(pageText){
 // Appends to your div
 $('#myDiv').append(
   $(pageText) // parses returned html
     .find('#externalDiv') // gets it div
 );
})
```

But remember that online content publisher still has rights over his content, also remember that some tags link may be broken after importing.